# Only bottom half of my website is visible, happens in 3 out of 5 browsers... Why?

Tags: html, css, centering

I am making a portfolio website at www.magalidb.0fees.net and I am having some issues with correctly displaying my website in several browsers. The issue is that in some browsers, only the bottom half of the content (which is inside a container) is visible, and the top half is somewhere above reach, at the top of the browser window. To see an example, try opening my website in Firefox, Opera or Internet Explorer.

There are some validation errors, but those are not that urgent. None of those errors is related to the behavior of the website. The site is written in HTML5 by the way, and uses both regular CSS and CSS3.

The issue seems to be with the vertical centering. I center the content of the container both horizontically and vertically.

To center the container horizontically, I used the following CSS:

```
#container {
min-height: 100%; /* To make sure it reaches the bottom of the browser page */
width: 940px;
margin-left: auto; /* Center horizonticallly */
margin-right: auto; /* Center horizontically */
overflow: hidden;
overflow-y: hidden; /* Vertical scrollbar fix for IE */ }
```

The vertical centering has the following CSS:

```
#valigner {
width: 720px;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
bottom: 50%;
height: 500px;
margin-top: -45%;   
margin-bottom: -45%;
margin: -40% 0 0 220px; }
```

The 220px is only so that the content and header won't stick behind the sidebar.

This is a general layout of the code in the body of my index page:

```
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="sidebar" class="left">
    <?php include('sidebars/sidebar.php'); ?>
    </div>
<div id="valigner">
    <div id="sidebar-bottom" class="left"></div>
    <div id="head" class="right"><h1>Magali&#39;s portfolio</h1></div>
    <div id="main" class="right">
        <div id="content-textbox">
            <div class="intro-left">
                Text comes here.
                            </div>
            <div class="intro-right">
                <img alt="Me!" class="resizeProfile" src="images/magali.jpg">
            </div>
        </div> <!-- Closing of div content-textbox -->
    </div> <!-- Closing of div main -->
    <div id="footer" class="right">
        <?php include('language.php'); ?>
    </div>
</div> <!-- Closing of div valigner -->
</div> <!-- Closing of div container -->
</body>
```

Please check out my website (http://www.magalidb.0fees.net). It displays correctly in Chrome and Safari, but incorrectly in Firefox, Opera and Internet Explorer.
I'm very puzzled about this, so any help is very welcome.

---

### !!!EDIT!!!

I found it! It works perfectly now.

I replaced the code from both container and valigner, to the following:

```
#container {    
position: absolute; 
top: 50%; 
width: 100%; 
height: 1px; 
overflow: visible;
}

#valigner { 
position: absolute; 
left: 50%; 
width: 940px; 
margin-left: -470px;
height: 540px; 
top: -270px 
}
```

The code explains itself, it's just so logical. I searched for an alternative method on centering content horizontally and vertically and found this. I feel silly now because I used this method before, yet I neglected it because I thought it was outdated...

Thank you guys for your help anyway! It is greatly appreciated. ;)

PS: I can't answer my own post. I tried, but I get a notification: "Users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. You may self-answer in 5 hours. Until then please use comments, or edit your question instead.".
So I edited my question, like the notification suggested me. I plan on editing the question again after those 5 hours and post an answer the correct way, but until then I can't do better than this. Sorry!

Comment: In your vertical centering, you are using absolute positioning, but no left property is set.  That may be an issue.  On Firefox, bring up firebug and look at the layout of your elements, and see what is happening.

Comment: `min-height: 100%` may not accurately make the container 100% tall. You should double check that in firebug as well.

Comment: Also, looking at your actual site, all the paddings and margins and position absolutes clutter the design, and will give you inconsistent results across browsers. A better option, if you wanted, say, a centered div of a certain width (in your case, 940px?) would be to just do that, and let the positioning be normal, inline inside of it.

Comment: "both regular CSS and CSS3"??? Since when was CSS3 not part of regular CSS? Also you might want to post that edit as an answer instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you've answered your question, but I'm a bit perplexed about how you've coded your site. There may be a valid reason for it, and if so, a moderator can delete my comment, but I don't think you need all the positioning stuff, especially on both the `#container` and `#valigner` elements. In fact, I reckon you could do it using 2 attributes on the `#container` elements, not using any messy `position: absolute;` techniques or anything. Here is my suggestion:

```
#container {
    width: 940px; // or whatever you want the width to be. I think this is what you specified originally.
    margin: 25px auto; // Centre the design in the middle of the page and put it 25px from the top and bottom of the browser window.
}
```

I reckon that's it. You could delete `#valigner` and just use this. If you carry on using `position: absolute;` everywhere, especially on your top-most containing elements, it will all start to get very messy later on.

Comment: I never knew this was possible using only 2 attributes! Very interesting. It does work, but the container sticks to the top of the browser window when I do this.